# Using Perl on command prompt to populate previous commands and make it editable

Tags: regex, perl, mod-perl

I have an application in perl that run on command line windows. I want to keep track of all commands used in the perl application so I can reuse it. The tricky part is the command I choose must be editable. Right now the only way to do that is to use backspace. Left and right arrow keys don't work. Here's an example:

On the command prompt, I type these commands and get the output (output omitted here).
>perlAppCommand1

>perlAppCommand2

>perlAppCommand3

>perlAppCommand4

Then I want to retrieve all commands by typing the command below:

>ShowPastCommands

I want to see this result:

1. perlAppCommand1
2. perlAppCommand2
3. perlAppCommand3
4. perlAppCommand4

Then I select the option number. For example, I choose 1. The 1st command will get populated on the command prompt like this.

>perlAppCommand1

I want to be able to edit this command on the command prompt by using the left and right keyboards. Right now I can only use back space. How do I enable edit the returned command with left and right arrow to move to the location?
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: This is now a question.

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if it fits the guideline.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very confusing, but if you want to be able to edit history in a command line prompt, take a look at the [Term::Readline](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Term%3a%3aReadline) CPAN modules.

Comment: I edited the question so it makes more sense what I want to do.